# making visible from one frame by another frame

Tags: javascript, asp.net, frameset

here im using 2 frames in a frameset

```
1.<frame name="leftmenu" src="left.aspx" />
2.<frame name="mainpage" src="main.aspx" />
```

in leftmenu in having treeveiw and one button(button name = backBut)**backBut.visible=false.**

in mainpage im dislpying list of search resultls(like google search results) in datalist, each result consists of **href**.

```
public datatable()
{
datatable dt=new datatable(); 
DataRow row;
row = dt.NewRow();                                                
string hypLink = "  <a style=\"COLOR: red;FONT: bold \" href=\"" + temp + "?keyword=" + key + "\">";
hypLink += "<br/><br/>" + title + "</a><br/>";
row["title"] = hypLink;
dt.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

now the question is, if clicked the **href** link in mainpage frame, i have to make **backBut.visible=true** which is in the leftmenu frame.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

I believe instead of an "a" tag you could use a LinkButton and set the OnClick Event to display the button

```
protected void linkbuttonhref_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  backbut.visible = true;
}
```